# How to Implement Singleton Pattern without Nullable

Tags: design-patterns, singleton, hhvm, hacklang

I am trying to implement the Singleton pattern in Hack. However, I keep running into issues with Nullable.

```
<?hh //strict

class Foo {
    private static Foo $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        // Do stuff here.
    }        

    public static function theFoo(): Foo {
        if (null === self::$foo) {
            self::$foo = new Foo();
        }

        return self::$foo;
    }
}

$aFoo = Foo::theFoo();
```

When executed I get the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Hack type error: Please assign a value at foo.hh line 4
```

The type checker returns a similar as well:

```
foo.hh:4:24,27: Please assign a value (Typing[4055])
```

How do I assign a default value to a static property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I assign a default value to a static property?

If it's an object, like in this case, you can't. With primitives, you can do something like this:

```
<?hh // strict

class Foo {
  private static int $x = 0;
  // ...
}
```

However, for objects, you'd need to say `private static Foo $x = new Foo()` which isn't allowed -- you can't initialize static variables like that, since it has to call the constructor, which involves running code, and PHP doesn't have a notion of initialization order and running code like this (which other languages, notably C++, do). There's no deep technical reason we couldn't have such a notion, it's just not part of the language right now.

The right thing to do is just make the static [nullable](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.nullable.php). You're actually already implicitly treating it as such, when you do the `if (null === self::$foo)` -- as written, `self::$foo` actually can't be null since you haven't given it a nullable type, and so that check does nothing. What you probably mean to do is this:

```
<?hh // strict

class Foo {
  private static ?Foo $foo;
  // ...
}
```

Comment: You mentioned: "You're actually already implicitly treating it as such, when you do the `if (null === self::$foo)`" The only reason I have to check if it is null is because I can't initialize it. So is this pattern impossible in Hack? I don't want to mark it as Nullable as it really isn't it should always be set and I don't want null checks all over my codebase when I access that property.

Comment: But it's not always set, not until you call `Foo::theFoo`, and so has to be nullable. However, you don't need null checks through all your code -- the return type of `Foo::theFoo` is not nullable, and so callers of that function don't need a null check. `Foo::theFoo` encapsulates the null check and does the right thing if it finds that it is null. So you're fine as long as you don't access `$foo` directly, and the way your code is written, it looks like that was the intent anyways.

Comment: If I have the `Foo::$foo` property set as nullable and then I return `self::$foo` from `Foo::theFoo()` as a non-nullable value the type checker gives a `Invalid return type (Typing[4110])` error saying the return value is incompatible with a nullable type. This indicates to me that the return type hint for `Foo::theFoo()` should be nullable and that I will need null checks anywhere I reference it.

Comment: No, the return type doesn't need to be nullable, Hack is control-flow sensitive so patterns like this one will work. Can you post a link to exactly the code you're hitting this in, and exactly the error you got, so I can see if this is a problem with your code or a bug in the typechecker?